# Vue3 composition API template replacement without eval

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

So, I'm building a system that allows users to create document templates. I have a pretty simple, human readable way of adding "dynamic" data to the templates:

#firstName from client#" <--- where "client" is a ref(), and firstName would be a property of that object.

Now, I can figure out how to replace these tags with the actual data without using eval(). Now, obviously I can't trust what people enter here, so I have an array of "allowedTags", and when I parse, I only parse the RegEx matched list of #..# values. So they can't do anything like #someEvil code here from SomeOtherEvilStuff" because it won't be an allowed tag.

Is this really that bad, or is there another way to dynamically replace using ref() values?

```
    function processTemplate(text: string): string {
      const re = new RegExp(/#\w+ from \w+#/, 'g')
      const matches = text.match(re) ?? []

      for (const match of matches) {
        if (!allowedTemplateTags.includes(match)) {
          continue
        }
        const split = match.replace(/#/g, '').split(' from ')
        const replaceRegEx = new RegExp(`(${match})`, 'g')
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument
        text = text.replace(replaceRegEx, eval(`${split[1]}?.value.${split[0]}`))

      }

      return text

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want is access variables of which you get the name from the user? My approach would be to have [a reactive data object](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state) and just use the strings to point at the correct entry.

```
import { reactive } from ‘vue’;

// For the idea: these two strings you get from the user
const string1 = ‘firstName’;
const string2 = ‘client’;

const data = reactive({ 
   client: {
      firstName: ‘John’,
   });

const text = data[string2][string1] // text will be ‘John’
data[string2][string1] = ‘Anna’; // now firstName will be ‘Anna’
```

I did not test this code, but I think you get the idea.

Hope this helps.